# memcached 1.6 make failure

Tags: libmemcache

Trying to build memcached 1.6, but fails with below error.
How to solve the problem?

libtool: compile:  gcc -std=gnu99 -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I./include -I./libevent -I./engines/default_engine -I./include -I./libevent -fvisibility=hidden -pthread -g -O2 -Wall -Werror -pedantic -Wmissing-prototypes -Wmissing-declarations -Wredundant-decls -MT default_engine_la-assoc.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/default_engine_la-assoc.Tpo -c engines/default_engine/assoc.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/default_engine_la-assoc.o
mv -f .deps/default_engine_la-assoc.Tpo .deps/default_engine_la-assoc.Plo
/bin/sh ./libtool  --tag=CC   --mode=compile gcc -std=gnu99 -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.  -I./include -I./libevent  -I./engines/default_engine -I./include -I./libevent   -fvisibility=hidden -pthread -g -O2 -Wall -Werror -pedantic -Wmissing-prototypes -Wmissing-declarations -Wredundant-decls -MT default_engine_la-default_engine.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/default_engine_la-default_engine.Tpo -c -o default_engine_la-default_engine.lo `test -f 'engines/default_engine/default_engine.c' || echo './'`engines/default_engine/default_engine.c
libtool: compile:  gcc -std=gnu99 -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I./include -I./libevent -I./engines/default_engine -I./include -I./libevent -fvisibility=hidden -pthread -g -O2 -Wall -Werror -pedantic -Wmissing-prototypes -Wmissing-declarations -Wredundant-decls -MT default_engine_la-default_engine.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/default_engine_la-default_engine.Tpo -c engines/default_engine/default_engine.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/default_engine_la-default_engine.o

engines/default_engine/default_engine.c: In function âinitalize_configurationâ:
engines/default_engine/default_engine.c:506:22: error: variable âretâ set but not used [-Werror=unused-but-set-variable]

cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
make[1]: *** [default_engine_la-default_engine.lo] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/user123/Downloads/memcached-1.6.0_beta1'
make: *** [all] Error 2

Comment: Can you post the compiler version and os your trying to build on?

Comment: Compiler : g++ (GCC) 4.7.0 20120507, OS : Fedora-17